# Do I need to apply for a Korean Tourist visa?

Tags: japan, tourist-visas, south-korea, filipino-citizens, philippines

I am a Philippine passport Holder with valid Japanese working visa residing in Japan. 
Do I need to apply for a Korean Tourist visa?

Comment: Did you check Timatic?

Answer (score 1):

According to Timatic, you do need a visa to enter the Republic of Korea, as well as evidence that you have to right to re-enter Japan (either stamped in your passport or the separate travel document issued to foreign residents).

Timatic is used by airlines to verify cross-border passenger documentation requirements. While perhaps not your carrier, [Emirates has an easy and accessible search tool](https://www.emirates.com/english/plan_book/find_visa_requirements/find_visa_requirements.aspx) which you can use to check on your own.

Comment: Someone who doesn't know what Timatic is would probably appreciate a link to support this...